# how do I bypass ZwQueryInformationProcess as anti-debugging protection

Tags: windows, ollydbg, anti-debugging

How do I defeat the `ZwQueryInformationProcess()` anti-debugging protection for the ProcessDebugPort class? 
Unlike `isDebuggerPresent()` I found this really hard to bypass in my skill...

Does anyone know how to bypass this api function?

Comment: it requires a driver to intercept the function and change the behavior.  It can't be bypassed at the application level.

Comment: @peterferrie if it is a query for ProcessDebugPort cant we overwrite the OutBuff  on returning from syscall

Comment: @blabb, to do that you would have to hook the syscall itself, because anything higher than that can be bypassed, and now you're a driver.  Then you have to track which process is being checked, since remote process with debugger might be legitimate.  Process handle might not be -1, but real handle which would require resolving first.

Comment: @peterferrie i posted an answer can you please take a look and tell if this cant be done ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include "zwopenproc.h"
int main (void) 
{
    hNtdll=GetModuleHandle("ntdll.dll");
    if(hNtdll) 
    {
        *(FARPROC *)&ZwQIP  = GetProcAddress(hNtdll,"ZwQueryInformationProcess");
        hProc=OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS,FALSE,GetCurrentProcessId());
        ZwQIP(hProc,ProcessImageFileName,OutBuff,sizeof(OutBuff),&Rlen);
        printf("ImageName=%wZ\n",OutBuff);
        ZwQIP(hProc,ProcessDebugPort,&DbgPort,4, &Rlen);
        switch( DbgPort )
        {
        case 0xffffffff:
            printf("some bugs are debugging us\n");
            break;
        case 0x0:
            printf("no bugs are debugging us\n");
            break;
        default:
            printf ("who knows if bugs are debugging us\n");
            break;
        }       
    }
    return 0;    
}
```

**executing this code without debugger**

```
zwopenproc.exe
ImageName=\Device\HarddiskVolume4\test\zwqiproc\zwopenproc.exe
no bugs are debugging us
```

**executing inside debugger results in detection**

```
cdb -g -G zwopenproc.exe | tail -2
ImageName=\Device\HarddiskVolume4\test\zwqiproc\zwopenproc.exe
some bugs are debugging us +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
```

**executing inside debugger and overwriting the return buffer using a script results in no detection**

```
cdb -G -c "$$>a< zwqip.txt" zwopenproc.exe  | tail -6


    Process Id  2064
    Parent Process  3716
    Base Priority 8
.  0    id: 810 create  name: zwopenproc.exe
ImageName=\Device\HarddiskVolume4\test\zwqiproc\zwopenproc.exe
no bugs are debugging us  <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<

printf "%x\n" , 2064
810
```

**contents of script file**

```
cat zwqip.txt
bp ntdll!ZwQueryInformationProcess ".if( poi(@esp+8) != 7 ){gc} .else { !handle poi(@esp+4
) f ; | ; gu ; ed dbgport 0; gc } "
g
```

Comment: sure, but now change GetCurrentProcessId() to another pid and then debug that pid legitimately.  Unless your script knows which handle refers to your process (can also be -1 for current process, or even a random handle value), you'll either hide the legitimate case and reveal yourself, or fail to report the error and reveal yourself.